# Adding 7 days to a Friday?

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I have to add 7 days to a Friday from a `DateTimePicker`. Here's my code.

I know that it creates a loop because 7 days from Friday is Friday. Then it repeats itself, how can I stop it from repeating after the first Friday?

```
        If Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday _
        Or Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
            If Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Then
                Me.DateTimePicker1.Value = Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(-1)
            Else
                Me.DateTimePicker1.Value = Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(-2)
            End If
        End If
        If Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Friday Then
            Me.DateTimePicker1.Value = Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(7)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I'm guessing that is in a change event?

Comment: yeah, thats what it is. you answer helped me out a lot. I'm new to programming and to this site, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Create a global state variable:

```vb
Dim busy as Boolean
busy = False
```

In your sub, you do something like this:

```vb
Sub dateTimePicker1Change...
     if not busy then 

          busy = True  
          ' Your logic here
          busy = False
     End if
End Sub
```

So with this, your event should fire twice, but when it is fired the second time while you are still processing the first event, you have set your `busy` state to `True` which immediately leads to a return of the second event handling (with no further triggering).

Comment: The 1980s called.  They want their `GoTo` back.

Comment: it's still basic ;)

Comment: Why use `GoTo` instead of `If Not busy Then`?

Comment: From VB I know `On Error GoTo` and normally, I would just return from a function in any other language in that situation. But while this is not possible in VB and a return using a `GoTo` seemed a convenient way to me, I used this. I believe that this is better readable than a bunch of conditional execution blocks.

Comment: `If busy Then Return` is not  "a bunch of conditional execution blocks"

Comment: Well, in the original code, there are some of them already, and my solution would have added an additional layer of nested if-clauses. However, I see your point, I will change the answer to avoid the goto.